# Can Eevee utilise one than one GPU when rendering?

Tags: eevee-render-engine, osx

Can Eevee utilise one than one GPU when rendering?

I've got a Mac pro 5.1 (Mojave) & have connected up 3xRX580 8GB GPU. Blender only uses one GPU when rendering, but DaVinci Resolve uses all 3 GPU to 100% (300%!) capacity.

Is there anything I can do to 'make' Blender 2.8 use the available GPUs?

Comment: Well, are they all selected in Blender's Parameters?

Comment: You can't. Eevee doesn't support multi GPU rendering (yet). Cycles can use multiple GPUs, but OpenCL has been deprecated by Apple, therefore GPU rendering with AMD graphics cards isn't supported on macOS. Blender currently doesn't use Metal or MoltenVK.